# How to map more than one level polymorphic one to many entity in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a model like this:

```
class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn()
    List<Base> baseClasses;
}
```

This is the base class:

```
@MappedSuperclass //tried to add strategy as well table per super class as well but it does not work
abstract class Base{
 
    //some fields here
}
```

The base class has two levels of children:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
class FirstLevel extends Base{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id
    
    //some fields here
}
```

```
@Entity
class SecondLevel extends FirstLevel{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id
    
    //some fields here
}
```

I am using spring data (hibernate). What I would like to achieve is map this class hierarchy into database structure like this:

- table Group which has one to many reference to specific base class
- specific base class - SecondLevel table

I would like to map this two level of Base hierarchy into one table which next will be accessible through `@OneToMany` mapping inside group table.

When I have `@MappedSuperclass` I am getting the following error:

> is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany
> targeting an unmapped class:

When I replace MappedSuperclass with Inheritance strategy -> TABLE_PER_CLASS
Hibernate requires two tables - FirstLevel and SecondLevel which I dont want.

To sum up - How do I map polymorphic relation oneToMany to multiple level of inheritance hierarchy ?

Comment: What table structure do you want?  Have you looked at the other inheritance strategies? docs if you need: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Comment: @Taylor I know all the strategies.
I can either chose MappedSupperclass (and and then it would be impossible to put this as type of Group items or TABLE_PER_CLASS but then i have additional table with duplicate IDs (Base) which I dont want as well. 
As far as my knowleadge goes this may be not possible with hibernate (except copy-paste fields in java)

Comment: What?  You keep talking about what you don't want.  What table structure do you want?